# more than one selection using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am doing a query to a db using Entity Framework, with this result i do more queries to check other things. So my question is, how can i do multiple selections in one query?.

For example:

```
var cars = db.Cars.ToList();
foreach (var car in cars) 
{
   var owners = db.Owners.Where(x => x.CarID == car.ID).Count();
}
```

So, i want to have the cars and the owners in the same result of a query.
I will apreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a projection:

```
var carsAndOwnerCounts = db.Cars
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Car = c,
        OwnerCount = db.Owners.Where(o => o.CarID == c.ID).Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

The result is a list of anonymous objects where each element has a `Car` and an `OwnerCount` property.